# Specify Action on sub-controller when using Html.RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a UserControl that I call with Html.RenderAction(...), so far so good..
Then I want to specify in the user control, which action should be used

```
Html.BeginForm("DeleteComment", "Comments", new { Id = "frmDelete" }, FormMethod.Post);%>
  <%= Html.SubmitImage( "imgbtnDelete", "/image.png", new { ... })%> 
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

And therein lies my problem; this calls the user control's controller/action.

What I want to happen is to call the pages action first and then be able to specify what action to call on the user control's controller.

Is this possible??
Thanks from an MVC noob

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? AFAIK, SubmitImage isn't part of MVC v1 RTM.

Comment: @Dan: SubmitImage is part of MVC v1 Futures

Comment: Yes, I'm using the MVC Futures

Comment: But, that is immaterial, it could be any control; the question remains -> how can I specify a sub controller/action through Html.RenderAction(..)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to set the action of the form to be `/{sub-controller}/{action-method}`

Something like

```
Html.BeginForm("DeleteComment", "Comments", new { Id = "frmDelete", action="/{sub-controller}/{action-method}" }, FormMethod.Post);%>
```

HTH,

Dan

Comment: The thing is that this control is on multiple pages, so I want the default Controller / Action to fire and then be able to specify which sub controller/action to use. So I cant use the "DeleteComment", "Comments" part

Comment: Could you pass the relevant "action" down in ViewData or your model?